# Is there any research on how users scan Pinterest or Trello style pages?

Tags: user-behavior

I'm working on a web app that integrates a Pinterest-like layout.

Question: Is there any research around how users scan Pinterest-style pages?

Illustration:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSRgiK.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Is it Left to right (fig.1) or top down in each column (fig.2), before scrolling?

Comment: Trello has vertical grouping of cards. So people would take the second approach.

Comment: I would _think_ that it's more likely that, on Pinterest, people jump around erratically by following what's most eye-catching, rather than following some order. Trello users might behave different since it's mostly just text

Answer (score 2):

**[Here](http://mashable.com/2011/11/30/social-profile-eye-tracking/#view_as_one_page-gallery_box3273)** you can find the results of an eye tracking study about where people focus their attention on popular websites.
The websites analyzed include Pinterest (it's the last one on the list):

[image]

The study was conducted by EyeTrackShop, a startup that runs eye-tracking studies.

Unfortunately I haven't found similar studies about Trello so far (I'd be very interested in reading them).

Comment: Great answer however not exactly what I was looking for. I would like to know how users scan through the various content boxes.